# Make class that return instance type in java and takes in 2 parameters

Tags: java, objective-c, instance

I have somewhat new to java and am trying to make a class/ mehtod that returns an instance type I have made the class in obj-c to demonstrate what I am trying to do, as I am more familiar with obj-c. And now I am tryin to make something similar in java, but am having some trouble I am not asking for a translation, just some guidance in a common mistake I might be making. Here is my obj-c code and then I post what I have tried in java.

```
- (instancetype)time:(NSString)weekday hour:(NSInteger)hour minute:(NSInteger)minute {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        timeFromWeek = weekday * 24 * 60 + hour * 60 + minute;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is what I am trying in java

```
public static class SomeContainer<E>
{
    E createContents(Class<E> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {


        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to pass in my parameters?

I have tried a bunch of things and I don't want to clog up this post with all of them, but will post if you think will help.

So I am  just wondering how I pass the parameters in like in the obj-c code.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It sounds like you should really read a Java tutorial or book. Stack Overflow is great for specific problems, but it's really not good as a starting point for learning a language. Look at whatever you're learning Java from, and find the bit about how to declare parameters - I'm sure it'll show you how to specify more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public static class SomeContainer<E>
{
    E createContents(Class<E> clazz, Object[] parameters) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        Class[] clzes = new Class[parameters.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
          clzes[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
        }
        Constructor<E> con = clazz.getConstructor(clzes);
        return con.newInstance(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `Object... parameters`, depending on how the questioner intends the method to be used.